# Search Email Of Last N Minutes Using IMAP-TOOLS

Tags: python, outlook, imap, imaplib, imap-tools

The following code uses `IMAP` to log into an Outlook email and checks the contents of the `Junk` folder.

It returns the content of the last unseen email with subject `"Title"`.

I would like to add one thing to the source code.

**Is it possible to get the last email of for example the last 10 minutes?** So that he doesn't return older emails.

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, AND

with MailBox('imap.outlook.com').login(email, password, 'Junk') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch(AND(subject = f'title', seen = False), limit = 1, reverse = True):
        body = msg.text
    for line in body.splitlines():
        print(line)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python imaplib search email with date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054196/python-imaplib-search-email-with-date-and-time)

Comment: You can however remember the UID of the last message you processed, and only search for messages newer than that.  The raw search term would be 'UID SEARCH UID n:*' where n is the last message you saw.  Note this will return the last message you saw as well, so you can filter it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no search by time in IMAP REF: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4

Anyway you can do it:

```
import datetime
from imap_tools import MailBox, A

# get emails that have been received since a certain time
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'p', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch(A(date_gte=datetime.date(2000, 1, 1))):
        print(msg.date.time(), 'ok' if msg.date.hour > 8 else '')
```

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools , I am author

Comment: I am getting authentication failed error using imap_tools but i am getting success login using imaplib.